# How to reuse dynamic variable {{$randomFirstname}} value in multiple requests in a postman collection

Tags: collections, postman

Tried following pre requested script

var name = '{{$randomFirstName}}';
pm.globals.set("Firstname", name);

var Lname = '{{$randomLastName}}';
pm.globals.set("Lastname", Lname);

pm.variables.set("name",pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$randomFirstName}}") )
pm.variables.set("name",pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$randomLastName}}") )

pm.collectionvariables.set("name",pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$randomFirstName}}") );
pm.collectionvariables.set("name",pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$randomLastName}}") );

used name, Lname in request body

Service1

"firstName": "{{name}}",
"lastName": "{{Lname}}",

request is throwing error on all the scripts. for each request different names are getting generated. These services are related to one employee

Comment: Each request in the collection ?  Use the pre request only in first request , and use that variable in the remaining request

Answer (score 11):

It's a dynamically changing value so each time you use it, it will set a new value in the variable.

Set it once in the `pre-request` to a local variable and then use that to set the `global` variable.

```js
var name = pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$randomFirstName}}"); 
pm.globals.set("Firstname", name);

var Lname = pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$randomLastName}}"); 
pm.globals.set("Lastname", Lname);
```

Then use `{{name}}` and `{{Lname}}` syntax in the other requests.